# Unable to align table view cell content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I, for the life of me, cannot get this issue to work out. I'm trying to align objects in my table view cell, but for some reason they aren't obeying the pins.

I formatted my layout like this:
[image]

And this is what I get in return:
[image]

Every object immediately shoots to the top left corner of the cell and I'm not sure why. I've looked at other questions on this topic, but they have not produced any helpful information. Any help I receive is appreciated.

**Here's some additional information**

Label constraints within the cell:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: please don't post *images* of code... post the actual code. To help debug something like this, start by giving your label a background color - will make it **much** easier to see where the label is actually being placed.

Comment: @DonMag Understood. It's not crucial to what I'm trying to get across so I'll make necessary changes.

Comment: Did you try setting a background color on your label? If so, can you post a screen-cap of how that turned out?

Comment: These three constraints cannot hold the label there. You need at least a fourth one like the height of the label

Comment: @FangmingNing - UILabel has intrinsic height and width ... those three constraints *are* enough.

Comment: @DonMag I just tried it, but nothing changed. It looks just like the image above, but with a background color added.

Comment: Are the labels with the background color showing as 75 width? (that's why I said post an image)

Comment: I changed it to match that width, but nothing changed. I added a screenshot. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Start fresh... delete the current Prototype cell... drag a new cell onto the table view... add a label to that cell... set *only* left and centerY constraints... give it a background color so you can see its bounding box when you run the app... don't forget to assign your custom class and Reuse Identifier, and connect the label to an IBOutlet... see what happens.

Comment: @DonMag That actually worked. A fresh start was all I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code - its with your constraints. If you are using the latest version of Xcode, you can manually set the positions of all the items in your cell programmatically or through storyboard for each device size. To do this, click on the View as: iPhone "x". Refer to the screenshot.[image]

Comment: I thought the pins were supposed to conform to the various device types available. Is there anything you could tell me about my constraints that would allow me to align them the way I want?

Comment: Get rid of your current constraints and replace it with these two constraints: one that sets the distance from the left side of the cell and another that sets the distance from the top of the cell.

Comment: No dice. Any kind of constraints seem to mess up the label position.